# Controlling a synth like QSynth via hardware midi knobs

Tags: midi

So I'm at a bit of a loss, as a bit of a newbie to linux and DAWs.

I'm basically hoping to use some midi hardware knobs on ubuntu studio to control the aspects of it's sounds, just basic things like drive and prescence.... and I can't figure out how.

I know how to log what midi outputs my keyboard puts out, I'm skilled with jack, and I know how to, using alsa but not jack, trigger different things with an output.

Answer (score 0):

How a synthesizer reacts to controller messages depends on that synthesizer.

QSynth is a wrapper for FluidSynth, which [documents some of its controllers](https://sourceforge.net/p/fluidsynth/wiki/FluidFeatures/), and also refers to sections 8.2.1 (not 8.1.2) and 9.6 of the SoundFont Technical Specification. FluidSynth does not allow to customize these controller assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your comments, after quite some research I learned you can pretty easily feed midi into midicontrol, then feel that into the control of Jack Rack - I have by 8 knobs controlling reverb, tremelo, amp, warmth, flanger, and a multiband eq divided into thirds. Works great and easy to set up!

Just feed me synth into it's audio and that back into the system, only downside is it doesn't seem possible to trigger the effects to turn on, only off.

Comment: So were you able to control the fluidsynth/Qsynth effects parameters with hardware? I have an Akai MPK mini that I can program any CC codes into but I don't know what codes to assign for the controls in Qsynth. The documentation for fluidsynth's CC codes is clear as mud.